# different style for code and text in php html css

Tags: php, html, css

I use `tinymce` editor in my page to write some text, some codes and this will be saved in mysql database in the database the text is like this:

> <p>i have a problem in my code</p> <p
>   style="text-align:
>   left;"><code>if(isset($_POST['Add'])){</code></p>
>   <p style="text-align: left;"><code>&nbsp;
>   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
>   $pr=secure($_POST['txt_pr'],"num");&nbsp;</code></p>
>   <p style="text-align:
>   left;"><code>if(empty($title) || empty($code) ||
>   empty($tags)){</code></p> <p style="text-align:
>   left;"><code>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
>   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
>   header("location:ask.php?msg=6");</code></p>
>   <p style="text-align: left;"><code>&nbsp;
>   &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
>   }</code></p> <p>some text here</p>

to transform this for a read it code i use

`highlight` and `php` function `htmlspecialchars_decode()` and

```
<pre><code></code></pre>
```

my problem is all this information code and text appear like a one block not like here in `stackoverflow` the code appear with gray background and the text white background.
How can out my result like `stackoverflow`???

```
text{background:white}
code{backgrounf:gray}
text{background:white}
```

i print my result like that:

```
  <pre><code dir='ltr'>  <?php echo $code;?>   </code></pre>
```

I hope my idea is clear :)

Comment: typo? `code{backgrounf:gray}` --> `code{background:gray}`

Comment: Also you might want to use the function `nl2br($yourHtmlStuff)`, that converts newlines to `<br>` tags: http://php.net/manual/de/function.nl2br.php

Comment: @Tagas thank you for your comment i use highlight and give me a background and specific color for the code put the backround is the same for the text and the code not like here each one have different color

Answer (score 0):

what i get is, when you get content form editor use raw format.

```
tinymce.activeEditor.getContent({format: 'raw'}
```

format row give raw html, i update a codepen, i get raw content and put in a div and it look like the same way, you can review,

[live code pen with raw format](https://codepen.io/mu92/pen/zjYKQw)

Comment: Can you explain more please ?

Comment: yes, when you get content, you are not specifying format. that's why when you show output it did not look like same as in editor. there is other format you can check the doc,